# Matplotlib and Pandas Plotting amount of numbers in certain range

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have pandas Dataframe that looks like this:

[image: DataFrame]

I am asking to create this kind of plot for every year [1...10] with the Score range of [1...10].
**This means that for every year, the plot will present:**

```
how many values between [0-1] have in year 1
how many values between [2-3] have in year 1
how many values between [4-5] have in year 1
.
.
.
.
.
how many values between [6-7] have in year 10
how many values between [8-9] have in year 10
how many values between [10] has in year 10
```

[image: Plot Example]

Need some help, Thank you!

Comment: Please first try it yourself or share your current state of your code, so that we can help you with your code instead of wrtiting the code for you. Also see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: We are not a code writing service. We help you write your codes. Pls show us what you have done till now.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works perfectly:

```
def visualize_yearly_score_distribution(ds, year):

sns.set_theme(style="ticks")

first_range = 0
second_range = 0
third_range = 0
fourth_range = 0
fifth_range = 0
six_range = 0
seven_range = 0
eight_range = 0
nine_range = 0
last_range = 0
score_list = []

for index, row in ds.iterrows():
    if row['Publish Date'] == year:
        if 0 < row['Score'] < 1:
            first_range += 1
        if 1 < row['Score'] < 2:
            second_range += 1
        if 2 < row['Score'] < 3:
            third_range += 1
        if 3 < row['Score'] < 4:
            fourth_range += 1
        if 4 < row['Score'] < 5:
            fifth_range += 1
        if 5 < row['Score'] < 6:
            six_range += 1
        if 6 < row['Score'] < 7:
            seven_range += 1
        if 7 < row['Score'] < 8:
            eight_range += 1
        if 8 < row['Score'] < 9:
            nine_range += 1
        if 9 < row['Score'] < 10:
            last_range += 1
score_list.append(first_range)
score_list.append(second_range)
score_list.append(third_range)
score_list.append(fourth_range)
score_list.append(fifth_range)
score_list.append(six_range)
score_list.append(seven_range)
score_list.append(eight_range)
score_list.append(nine_range)
score_list.append(last_range)
range_list = ['0-1', '1-2', '2-3', '3-4', '4-5', '5-6', '6-7', '7-8', '8-9', '9-10']

plt.pie([x*100 for x in score_list], labels=[x for x in range_list], autopct='%0.1f', explode=None)
plt.title(f"Yearly Score Distribution for {str(year)}")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Thank you all for the kind comments :)
This case is closed.